# How to set layout for two tablet with different resolutions but same size?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on an android app for tablets with 800*400 with mdpi resolution. but as per the requirements I have to make the app for 800* 400 with ldpi resolution. I have made different layouts for both the tablets and specified folders /layout and /layout-large.But still only large is working . I am not able to understand how to make it work in one app. Please help?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What do you mean by "only large is working"? Did you test it on mdpi/ldpi...and so on devices or emulators? For 800*400 it will always pick the layout-large files

Comment: can you tell us which are those tablets? I think then hdpi and xhdpi should work for you.. I dont think that tablets can be of "mdpi" but still you want to specify drawable based on density then see Table No. 1 in this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html .. those are only possible ways..

Comment: Both tablet sizes are 800*400 but one is ldpi and other is mdpi. Layout-large files are working.I have tested both on tablets and devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Layout-mdpi and layout-ldpi. For being more specific you can also define two different layouts in Layout-normal-mdpi and Layout-normal-ldpi.
Place your respective layouts in the these folders.